# Geoserver Configuration Reload

Tags: rest, curl, geoserver

Not quite sure if I should even be doing this.  What I am wanting is I will be dynamically generating my sld file and it looks like when you update the sld in the geoserver admin it does a reload.  So I tried to do a reload using the rest api and curl and it does not appear to work.
Here is my Curl

```
curl -uadmin:password-XPOST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/reload
```

If there is another way to clear everything so my sld reloads that'd be awesome as well.  Just needing to get this working and am not sure why it isn't.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked this on the GIS site and received an answer suitable for what I am doing.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7754/geoserver-configuration-reload

Answer (score 0):

This documentation on the REST API for Configuration Reloading may be what you are looking for...

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html#configuration-reloading

Your curl request seems pretty close, I only had to change it slightly and it worked in my environment...

curl -u admin:password **-v** -XPOST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/reload

If this doesn't work for you, can you describe more thoroughly in what way it is not working?